# Enumerating model choices in a Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a model that uses a Django choices field, like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
QUESTION_TYPES = (
    (10,'Blurb'),
    (20,'Group Header'),
    (21,'Group Footer'),
    (30,'Sub-Group Header'),
    (31,'Sub-Group Footer'),
    (50,'Save Button'),
    (100,'Standard Question'),
    (105,'Text-Area Question'),
    (110,'Multiple-Choice Question'),
    (120,'Standard Sub-Question'),
    (130,'Multiple-Choice Sub-Question')
)
type = models.IntegerField(default=100,choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
```

I'm using Django Rest Framework to present this model as an API to an Angular web app. In my Angular web app, I want a combo box widget that drops down with all those choices. Not the integers, but the text choices, like "blurb", "standard question" and so on.

Now, I could hand code the combo box into the Angular app, but in the spirit of DRY, is it possible to write a DRF serializer that just returns those choices (ie the QUESTION_TYPES object), so I can populate the combo box with a ReST query?

And by "possible", I guess I mean "simple and elegant". And maybe I also mean "ReSTful". (Is it ReSTful to do it that way?)

Just wondering . . .

Thanks

John

Comment: Expose that model through a URL.  In your AngularJS controller do a `$http.get()` to retrieve all the values.  Stick those values on the `$scope` variable ( call it `foo`).  Then reference that `foo` as an `ng-options` attribute of your `<select>` element.

Comment: The way I read your suggestion, that's just a regular API call, that would return all the rows in the table, isn't it? I don't want an API that returns  table rows - I already have that. I want an API that simply returns QUESTION_TYPES - 11 rows of data, even if the model's table itself is empty. I can't reliably reconstruct QUESTION_TYPES from table rows because there may not be any table rows of a given type.

Comment: Ah.  Then you could create a model that does have all values of that type.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably try something like the following:

```
# models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    QUESTION_NAMES = (
        'Blurb',
        'Group Header',
        'Group Footer',
        'Sub-Group Header',
        'Sub-Group Footer',
        'Save Button',
        'Standard Question',
        'Text-Area Question',
        'Multiple-Choice Question',
        'Standard Sub-Question',
        'Multiple-Choice Sub-Question')
    QUESTION_VALS = (10, 20, 21, 30,
                     31, 50, 100, 105, 110,
                     120, 130)
    QUESTION_TYPES = tuple(zip(QUESTION_VALS, QUESTION_NAMES))
    # Personal choice here: I never name attribs after Python built-ins:
    qtype = models.IntegerField(default=100,choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
```

---

**The following doesn't work as I thought it should**

(Following was my original intuition on serializing a list of objects, but it did not work. I'm leaving it in here anyway, because it seems like it should work.)

Okay, so we have a way to access the strings on their own, now we just need to serialize them, and for that, I'd probably try to use the `ListField` [in DRF3](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield), which should support the `source` kwarg, I would think?

```
# serializers.py
from .models import Question
class YourSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    names = serializers.ListField(
       child=serializers.CharField(max_length=40),
       source=Question.QUESTION_NAMES
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('names', etc.)
```

---

**The following does return a list of results**

Fallback: use a `SerializerMethodField`:

```
from .models import Question

class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    names = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_names(self, obj):
        return Question.QUESTION_NAMES

    class Meta:
        model = Question
```

**Demo:**

```
In [1]: q = Question.objects.create()
Out[1]: <Question: Question object>  

In [2]: ser = YourSerializer(q)

In [3]: ser.data
Out[3]: {'id': 1, 'names': ['Blurb', 'Group Header', 'Group Footer', 'Sub-Group Header', 'Sub-Group Footer', 'Save Button', 'Standard Question', 'Text-Area Question', 'Multiple-Choice Question', 'Standard Sub-Question', 'Multiple-Choice Sub-Question'], 'qtype': 100}
```

Comment: Did anyone test this and get it working? DRF didn't like the `source=QUESTION_NAMES` bit; errored out saying it couldn't split a tuple.

Comment: I put in an alternate way of doing it. I was really hoping that `ListField` would be the answer to stuff like this, but I was wrong. Reading the source on `ListField`, I'm not exactly sure where to use it.

Answer (score 5):

if you use a `ModelViewSet` in combination with a `ModelSerializer`, the `OPTIONS` request will return metadata that you can use to get the choice options.

```
from models import Question
from rest_framework import serializers

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question


from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
class QuestionChoicesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

This will give you a response that includes the `actions` attribute, that might look something like this:

```
"actions": {
    "POST": {
        "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "ID"
        },
        "qtype": {
            "type": "choice",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": false,
            "label": "Qtype",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "display_name": "Blurb",
                    "value": 10
                },
                {
                    "display_name": "Group Header",
                    "value": 20
                },
                {
                    "display_name": "Group Footer",
                    "value": 21
                },
                {
                    "display_name": "Sub-Group Header",
                    "value": 30
                },
                //...
        }
    }
}
```

You can iterate over the `choices` attribute on `qtype` to get all of the available choices.

To get more familiar with this topic you can read: [Metadata](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/)

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by making an API endpoint for the choices which only use the GET verb.

## models.py

```
QUESTION_TYPES = (
    (10,'Blurb'),
    (20,'Group Header'),
    (21,'Group Footer'),
    (30,'Sub-Group Header'),
    (31,'Sub-Group Footer'),
    (50,'Save Button'),
    (100,'Standard Question'),
    (105,'Text-Area Question'),
    (110,'Multiple-Choice Question'),
    (120,'Standard Sub-Question'),
    (130,'Multiple-Choice Sub-Question')
)

class Question(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(default=100,choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
```

## viewsets.py

```
from models import QUESTION_NAMES, Question
from rest_framework import serializers
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=QUESTION_NAMES, default=100)
    class Meta:
        model = Question

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class QuestionChoicesViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response(QUESTION_NAMES)

from rest_framework import viewsets
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```