# Provide REST endpoint to list unique values of model field

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a `Cat` model with these fields:

- name: free text
- size: enumerate value, BIG / MEDIUM / SMALL

I can get the list of cats in the following endpoint:

```
/api/v1/cat
```

The client has no knowledge about the sizes.

Is there an accepted DRF method of providing a REST endpoint to list the possible values of a certain model field? My first idea would be to offer the following endpoint:

```
/api/v1/cat/size
```

Replying with something like:

```
["BIG", "MEDIUM", "SMALL"]
```

But what model should I use for the response? Is there an standard way of providing this information with DRF?

Comment: It looks as though DRF may provide the list of model choices via an OPTIONS request to the end point, although the data returned would be more verbose than a simple list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727960/2091925

Answer (score 0):

I think `/api/v1/cats/sizes` is fine. It's quite clear to understand what that URL representate.

(Just change to plural. check [here](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/))